# GATE Tagging annotations for Numbers,Currency, Money

Tags: java, text-mining, gate

Please help.

I have some text 
   *" 99285/25
EMERGENCY SE
850.0
**650.00**
04/05/12*

INTERPRET
813.44
**$36.00**
04/05/12
CARLOS
"

I need to tag **650.00** also as Money, Gate automatically picks up **$36.00** as Money tag. How do I specify it?

```
Imports: { import static gate.Utils.*; }
Phase: Number  
Input: Token Number  
Options: control = all  

Macro: AMOUNT_NUMBER
({Token.kind == number}
(({Token.string == ","}|  
{Token.string == "."}  
   )  
   {Token.kind == number}  
  )
Rule: MoneyCurrencyUnit  
  (  
      (AMOUNT_NUMBER)  
  ({Number.majorType == currency_unit})  
  )  
:number --> 
  :number {
  {
  {kind = "number", rule = "MoneyCurrencyUnit"}
}
 catch(InvalidOffsetException e) {
 // not possible
 throw new LuckyException("Invalid offset from annotation");
   }
 }
```

I'm new using JAPE Grammar please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tag `650.00` as Money, you will also tag `813.44` (for example) as Money.

If you really want to do that you just have to modify your JAPE rule to match a `Token.kind == number` separated by a `.` or a `,` with `Token.kind == number` just after.

In other word, the same thing you did but with an optional `currency_unit`.

In JAPE, the `?` operator allow a pattern in parentheses to be optional.
You can probably try this:

```
Rule: MoneyCurrencyUnit  
  (  
      (AMOUNT_NUMBER)  
  ({Number.majorType == currency_unit})?  
  )
```